# Especificar múltiples condiciones de búsqueda en consulta

Tags: php, mysql, sql

El problema es que tengo este código que pertenece a un input de búsqueda donde introduces el nombre de un empleado y busca en la base de datos y te muestra un autocompletado de sus datos.

El detalle es que me muestra el de todos los clientes del portal y yo solo quiero que me muestre el del usuario que ingreso el dato, el que está logueado, el dato del perfil que insertó el dato está en la columna `$id_perfil`, pero no logro hacer la consulta bien.

```
    <?php
if (isset($_GET['term'])){
include("../../config/db.php");
include("../../config/conexion.php");
$return_arr = array();
/* If connection to database, run sql statement. */
if ($con)
{

    $fetch = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM clientes where nombre_cliente like '%" . mysqli_real_escape_string($con,($_GET['term'])) . "%' LIMIT 0 ,50"); 
    /* Retrieve and store in array the results of the query.*/
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($fetch)) {
        $id_cliente=$row['id_cliente'];
        $row_array['value'] = $row['nombre_cliente'];
        $row_array['id_cliente']=$id_cliente;
        $row_array['nombre_cliente']=$row['nombre_cliente'];
        $row_array['telefono_cliente']=$row['telefono_cliente'];
        $row_array['email_cliente']=$row['email_cliente'];
        $row_array['puesto']=$row['puesto'];
        $row_array['telefono_cliente']=$row['telefono_cliente'];
        array_push($return_arr,$row_array);
    }

}

/* Free connection resources. */
mysqli_close($con);

/* Toss back results as json encoded array. */
echo json_encode($return_arr);

}
?>
```

---

Lo intenté con:

```
$fetch = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM clientes where nombre_cliente like '%" . mysqli_real_escape_string($con,($_GET['term'])) . "%' LIMIT 0 ,50 AND id_perfil='".$_SESSION['user_id']."'" );
```

pero deja de funcionar el autocompletado.

Comment: ¿Podrías imprimir la consulta generada? Podrías almacenarla en una variable de texto, y luego la imprimes en pantalla, para saber qué es lo que realmente estás consultando, para saber por qué no te devuelve lo que buscas.

Comment: Puedes añadir multiples condiciones a la consulta utilizando los operadores logicos, en tu tu caso debes ocupar un `AND campo=$id_perfil` despues del LIKE. Algo como `WHERE campo LIKE valor AND campo=id_perfil`

Comment: lo intente con $fetch = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM clientes where nombre_cliente like '%" . mysqli_real_escape_string($con,($_GET['term'])) . "%' LIMIT 0 ,50 AND id_perfil='".$_SESSION['user_id']."'" ); pero deja de funcionar el autocompletado

Comment: @AbdielHernandez tu consulta no funciona porque has puesto una condición fuera del `where`, detrás del `limit 0,50`. Debería ser así: `"SELECT * FROM clientes where nombre_cliente like '%" . mysqli_real_escape_string($con,($_GET['term'])) . "%' AND id_perfil='".$_SESSION['user_id']."' LIMIT 0 ,50 "` (aplicado a tu código, realmente sería mejor con consultas preparadas).

Comment: Wow @AlvaroMontoro funciono! me habia dado mucho dolor de cabeza y era tan sencillo, muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El orden (simplificado) de los componentes de una consulta en MySQL es como sigue:

```
SELECT   campos
FROM     tablas
WHERE    condiciones
GROUP BY campos
HAVING   condiciones
ORDER BY campos
LIMIT    índices
```

Tu consulta no funciona porque has puesto una condición fuera del `where`, detrás del `limit` (la parte de `... LIMIT 0,50 AND id_perfil= ...`), lo que va a causar un error de sintaxis y que la consulta falle.

Debería cambiarlo para que el `limit` quede al final (aplicado a tu código, realmente sería mejor con consultas preparadas como te recomiendan otros usuarios):

```
$fetch = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM clientes where nombre_cliente like '%" . mysqli_real_escape_string($con,($_GET['term'])) . "%' AND id_perfil='".$_SESSION['user_id']."' LIMIT 0 ,50 " );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    <?php

if(!isset($_SESSION['usuario_id'])): /// Si no existe la SESSION...

print 'Debes iniciar sesión para el autocompletado';

else:

if(!is_numeric($_SESSION['usuario_id'])): /// Verificamos si es una ID con la funcion IS_NUMERIC que devuelve true si la cadena es solo numeros.

    print 'La cadena tiene un error la ID esta infectada';

else:

$usuario = htmlspecialchars($_SESSION['user_id']);

$query = $link->prepare("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE id=:usuario_id LIMIT 1");
$query->bindParam(":usuario_id", $usuario);
$query->execute(); 
$query->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

foreach($query as $resultado):

 $array = array ( 
                  "id" => $resultado['id'],
                  "usuario" => $resultado['usuario'],
                  "nombre"  => $resultado['nombre'],
                  "apellido" => $resultado['apellido']              
                                                          );
endforeach;

echo $array['id'];  /// Devuelve el ID


endif; endif;

?>
```

Primero hice un isset para comprobar si la session existe luego use la función is_numeric() que comprueba si la cadena tiene solo numeros luego limpie la cadena para que no queden dudas y hice la consulta con PDO

Comment: Hola andres, no termina de quedar claro cómo este código está relacionado con la pregunta. Por favor, lee [answer] donde encontrarás consejos y recomendaciones para mejorar tus respuestas. Un saludo.